# Haxe access Class<T> static fields

Tags: class, static, haxe

I have three classes and I would like to be able to call static functions from the returned `Class<Access>`. I would like to select class type based on conditions.

```
class Access {
    public static function get(item: Int): Int { return -1; }

    public static function getAccessType(): Class<Access> {
        if(Client.hasConnection())
            return Remote;
        else return Local;
    }
}
```

```
class Remote extends Access {
    override public static function get(item: Int): Int { return Server.getItem(item); }
}
```

```
class Local extends Access {
    override public static function get(item: Int): Int { return Client.getItem(item); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't override a static function in Haxe.
But you can probably achieve what you're trying to do by simply removing the override in Remote and Local

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with singletons.

However, still the question might relevant whether such feature in Haxe even exists.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on target, you may be able to cast a class to an interface/typedef to pull out values in a type-safe-ish way. "override" does not work for static methods

```
class Test {
    static function pick(z:Bool):HasGetItem {
        return z ? cast A : cast B;
    }
    static function main() {
        trace("Haxe is great!");
        trace(pick(false).getItem(1));
        trace(pick(true).getItem(2));
    }
}
@:keep class A {
    public static function getItem(i:Int):Int return 10;
}
@:keep class B {
    public static function getItem(i:Int):Int return 5;
}
typedef HasGetItem = {
    getItem:Int->Int
}
```

https://try.haxe.org/#b2b87